# How we can add write access to a directory programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, directory-security

I have an ASP.NET page that creates directories, and in another page I upload some files in these folders, but when I upload a file in a directory, the below error appears:

```
Access to the path 'my path' is denied.
```

Comment: more info: ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource

Comment: @masoud its your appthat is creating these apps so your app should have permission to write to these directories. Are you using a different username to create these directories?

Comment: My code for creating directory is :  Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath + "\\Thumbnails\\" + albumId);

Comment: and in this line I get the error : FileStream newFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

Comment: Not related to your access-problem but you should always use Path.Combine for building up your paths.

Comment: @ BurningIce : can you give me more info?

Comment: @masoud ramezani ~ you've given entirely not enough information to solve this problem. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for more advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running under a user account that does not have write access to the specified directory, so it is unlikely that same user would have access to change the permissions. This means that you will not be able to change the permissions from your code while it is running under that context. Remember that the code can do no more (permissions wise) than the user account allows.

You will need to set the permissions on the directory (or a parent directory) manually so that the ASP.NET user can write to it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using iis6 you need to grant the aspnet user permissions to that folder. 
if you are using iis7 you need to grant the IIS_IUSRS user permissions to that folder.